# Rails 5.1 Routes: dynamic :action parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5

Rails 5.0.0.beta4 introduced a deprecation warning on routes containing dynamic :action and :controller segments:

```
DEPRECATION WARNING: Using a dynamic :action segment in a route is deprecated and will be removed in Rails 5.1.
```

[The commit message from this PR](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/23980) states:

> Allowing :controller and :action values to be specified via the path
>   in config/routes.rb has been an underlying cause of a number of issues
>   in Rails that have resulted in security releases. In light of this
>   it's better that controllers and actions are explicitly whitelisted
>   rather than trying to blacklist or sanitize 'bad' values.

How would you go about "whitelisting" a set of action parameters? I have the following in my routes file, which are raising the deprecation warning:

```
namespace :integrations do
  get 'stripe(/:action)', controller: 'stripe', as: "stripe"
  post 'stripe/deactivate', controller: 'stripe', action: 'deactivate'
end
```

Comment: The obvious answer seems to be to explicitly define each action, but this seems cumbersome in a controller with many custom actions. Perhaps this is best practice anyway, n'est-ce pas?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Though it's a bit cumbersome, the best approach seems to be to explicitly define the routes:

```
namespace :integrations do
  namespace 'stripe' do
    %w(auth webhook activate).each do |action|
      get action, action: action
    end
  end
  post 'stripe/deactivate', controller: 'stripe', action: 'deactivate'
end
```

Comment: Just a minor comment. In `get action, action: action` you can leave out the action, since Rails defaults to the action with the same name as the get. Thus `get action` is sufficient.

Answer (score 4):

Is not the same case as you, but I did this:

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController
  def index
    render params[:path]
  end
end
```

Routes:

```
get ':path', to: 'pages#index'
```

I suppose if I want a nested path I will use `*`:

```
get '*path', to: 'pages#index'
```

Comment: Yeah, I chose a solution very similar to this. Are there any security concerns with doing this, though? One weird side-effect is that you can now visit the page for a partial. E.g. if you have `views/pages/_sidebar.html.erb`, you can now visit `/_sidebar`

Comment: This approach may be insecure - http://brakemanscanner.org/docs/warning_types/dynamic_render_paths/

Comment: @BradWerth I am aware this kind of code could be insecure, but in this case article does not give an example, `params[:path]` is a string, it will only look for a file matching path

Comment: Right, I was mainly responding to the unanswered question of @Obversity. I posted a link to a Rails ticket with examples of how this type of thing might be abused (directory traversal) in a different comment, I'll put it here, too, if you're curious. https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/27231#issuecomment-304650177

Comment: thanks, it's hard to understand too, I suppose to prevent that one could do something like `render params[:path] if File.exists?(Rails.root.join 'app', 'views', 'pages', params[:path]) && !params[:path].starts_with?('_')`... hmm but I suppose that's the reason they deprecated dynamic action... many cases there

Comment: an easy option could be accept only alpha in path `params[:path][/\A\w+\z/]`, I do not think partials will be rendered anyway, `render '_some'` does not work as far as I remember

Comment: Use the following code to check if the template exists. The third parameter specifies whether you want a partial. `lookup_context.template_exists?(params[:path], "pages", false)`.  [API doc](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/LookupContext/ViewPaths/template_exists%3F)

Comment: it has been suggested as a secure alternative [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/27231#issuecomment-371066748)

Answer (score -4):

It works like this:

```
get 'stripe(/:action)', controller: 'stripe', action: :action, as: "stripe"
```

Comment: That's exactly what has been deprecated.

Comment: @JamesMoore  Is there any documentation about the deprecated