# DEPRECATION WARNING: Using a dynamic :controller segment in a route is deprecated and will be removed in Rails 5.1

Tags: routes, ruby-on-rails-5

I have config/routes.rb with warning

```
DEPRECATION WARNING: Using a dynamic :controller segment in a route is deprecated and will be removed in Rails 5.1.
```

Don't know how to rewrite to remove the warning.
Any document to understand how todo. Or new code
Thx.

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  post ':controller(/:action(/:id))(.:format)'
  get ':controller(/:action(/:id))(.:format)'
  get '/logout' => 'sessions#destroy', :as => 'logout'
  get '/auth/failure' => 'sessions#failure'
  post '/auth/:provider/callback' => 'sessions#create'
  resources :sessions
  resources :identities
  root :to => 'myapp#index'
end
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rails 5.1 Routes: dynamic :action parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37008713/rails-5-1-routes-dynamic-action-parameters)

Comment: What the new rewrite of "post ':controller(/:action(/:id))(.:format)'
  get ':controller(/:action(/:id))(.:format)' "?

Comment: From surfing on the internet it seems to my that dynamic actions/controllers are phased out and there is no alternative. I imagine it has to do with the security of the application. The best solution I found so far is just whitelist all action, thus writing them all out, or looping through them, like shown in the answer of the duplicate question.

Comment: See: https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/23980

Comment: And: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/27231, @TheR2 (in the issue) has a workaround for `:action`, with some searching maybe this can be done for `:controller` as well.

Comment: Still confuse for me and don't know how to rewrite/replace post ':controller(/:action(/:id))(.:format)'
  get ':controller(/:action(/:id))(.:format)'

Answer (score 0):

Here what I did. 
Loop all get, It's feel like go back to hard code. 
But I don't know if any way better, So far work with Rails 5.2 beta

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  mount Ckeditor::Engine => '/ckeditor'
  post '/auth/:provider/callback' => 'sessions#create'
  get '/auth/:provider/callback' => 'sessions#create'
  get '/logout' => 'sessions#destroy', :as => 'logout'
```

> ```
>   jinda_methods = ['pending','status','search','doc','logs','ajax_notice']
>   jinda_methods += ['init','run','run_do','run_form','end_form']
>   jinda_methods.each do |aktion| get "/jinda/#{aktion}" => "jinda##{aktion}" end
> ```

```
  post '/jinda/pending' => 'jinda#index'
  post '/jinda/end_form' => 'jinda#end_form'
  get '/articles/my' => 'articles/my'
  resources :articles
  resources :identities
  resources :sessions
  resources :password_resets
  resources :jinda, :only => [:index, :new]
  root :to => 'jinda#index'
  # For details on the DSL available within this file, see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html
end
```